# Can someone please explain what this means exactly?

Tags: javascript

I found this line of code in a script function and I have no idea what it means or how to alter it. Here is the code:

> variable_name = window.document.form_name.page.value;

It had an actual form name instead of "form_name" but what exactly is this saying, I get that its setting the variable to something but its the something that I don't understand. I'm rather new to script so any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `page` is the name of an input field, and `value` is looking at the value held inside the input field. So the above code will store the value (if any) of the page input field (if it exists) into the `variable_name`.

This [JSFiddle shows how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/ULKgm/).

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the HTML, you will see something like:

```
<form name="form_name" ...>
    ...
    <input name="page" ...>  <!-- or <button> or <textarea> or whatnot -->
    ...
</form>
```

`window.document.form_name.page.value` is the current value — the currently-entered text — in the form-element named `page`.

Answer (score 0):

It's setting variable_name to the value of the page field contained in the form_name form. The field, page, may be hidden or visible.